# Analyze heap corruption dumps

Tags: c++, dll, visual-c++, crt

Sometimes, a process will use different editions of crt library, and this will cause heap corruption .

Bad use of allocated memeory will also cause heap corruption,  but it's hard to trace. what the best advice to debug this kind problem, I  can only analyze a minidump in most situations  ?

Thanks a lot！

Comment: @HansPassant:Sorry I've made a mistake, two msvcr80.dlls are not the same edition and I figured out the reason. So I'll just ask the other question.

Comment: No, a minidump is not useful to debug heap corruption.  At best, you can only see it being corrupted, you cannot tell what code produced it.  That code ran a long time ago.  You need to catch it when the corruption occurs.  A data breakpoint is a good way.  A debug allocator (like `<crtdbg.h>`) that lets you inject heap checks is good to narrow down the area of code where it happens.  If you know up front that you've got multiple CRTs loaded then that by itself is already a very good lead.  The debug heap available since Vista is very helpful.